# Report on a point in time

Tags: sql

I am about to create what I assume will be 2 new tables in SQL. The idea is for one to be the "live" data and a second which would hold all the changes. Dates are in DD/MM/YYYY format.

```
Active
ID | Name | State Date | End Date
1    Zac    1/1/2016     -          
2    John   1/5/2016     -          
3    Sam    1/6/2016     -          
4    Joel   1/7/2016     -          

Changes
CID | UID | Name | Start Date | End Date
1     1     Zac    1/1/2016     -
2     4     Joel   1/1/2016     -
3     4     Joel   -            1/4/2016    
4     2     John   1/5/2016     -
5     3     Sam    1/6/2016     -
6     4     Joel   1/7/2016     -
```

In the above situation you can see that Joel worked from the 1/1/2016 until the 1/4/2016, took 3 months off and then worked from the 1/7/2016.

I need to build a query where by I can pick a date in time and report on who was working at that time. The above table only lists the name but there will be many more columns to report on for a point in time.

What would be best way to structure the tables to be able to achieve this query.

Comment: here is a good article about different Slowly Changing Dimensions SCD types and structures it may simplify your life to keep it in the same table depending on other uses and requirements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Comment: Will have a read. Thanks!

Comment: DBMS of your choice may have some built-in support for this kind of task. For example, SQL Server 2016 implemented [Temporal tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I started writing this last night and finally coming back to it.  Basically you would have to use your change table to create a Slowly Changing Dimension and then generate a row number to match your start and ends.  This will assume however that your DB will never be out of sync by adding 2 start records or 2 end records in a row.

This also assumes you are using a RDBMS that supports common table expressions and Window Functions such as SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2....

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY ISNULL(StartDate,EndDate)) As RowNum
    FROM
       Changes c
)

SELECT
    s.UID
    ,s.Name
    ,s.StartDate
    ,COALESCE(e.EndDate,GETDATE()) as EndDate
FROM
    cte s
    LEFT JOIN cte e
    ON s.UID = e.UID
    AND s.RowNum + 1 = e.RowNum
WHERE
    s.StartDate IS NOT NULL
    AND '2016-05-05' BETWEEN s.StartDate AND COALESCE(e.EndDate,GETDATE())
```